# Problems with booting, most likely graphics issue

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics

I'm running a Lenovo ThinkPad L570 laptop with dual-boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. I was working like normal on Ubuntu, when the laptop suddenly crashed. I tried rebooting, but the boot process froze at

```
Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
```

Booting recovery mode and immediately selecting `Resume normal boot` still works like normal (except I can't change the screen brightness), as does booting Windows.

I assume this is an issue with the graphics driver, but I don't know where it came from. I've been using this machine for more than a year without any problems and I don't think the driver's been updated or changed recently.

Comment: If you could add some more info of your setup, that would help.

Comment: The system uses an integrated Intel HD 620 graphics chip.
I now believe this to be a hardware problem, as graphics problems now also appeared on Windows, though it still boots.